# Why does switch("d", a = 1, b = 2) not give any warning, error, or output?

Tags: r, switch-statement

Clearly, `switch("d", a = 1, b = 2)` does not have a default value, a value matching "d", or any reason to return anything. [The documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/switch) for `switch` tells us that "*A warning is signaled if no alternatives are provided, as this is usually a coding error*". However, when I run `switch("d", a = 1, b = 2)`, nothing happens at all. I get no outputs, warnings, or errors. What have I misunderstood about R's `switch`? I expected a warning.

Comment: That message about the warning is only when there are no matches supplied at all, ie `switch("d")`, not for the case when none of the alternatives match.

Comment: To understand what the documentation authors mean, try `switch(EX="d", a = 1, b = 2)` and `switch(ex="d", a = 1, b = 2)`

Comment: @IanCampbell That second example gives an error. Wouldn't a suitable example give a warning instead, as the documentation suggests?

Comment: If you are very curious you can see the C code for the function here: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/a2c6bba423f8ec1d23b9953bc088b567c26bbb88/src/main/builtin.c#L1030. You can see what will generate an error or warning.

Comment: @MrFlick I was just looking at that source page. Did you use `pryr::show_c_source` to find it or is there a better way?

Comment: @J.Mini The error is generated from the `check1arg` C function which can be found on line 496 of [this source](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/17a72a9634734e009094fd8b48e985b8597ced6a/src/main/util.c). The documentation is not 100% accurate.

Comment: @IanCampbell I don't know if it's "better" but I've just gotten used to browsing the R source code. I usually just look up the function name in `src/main/names.c` (usually it's just "do_" plus the function name), then search for that function's definition.

Comment: @IanCampbell, FYI, you can link directly to line numbers in files at Github by adding `#L{line number you want to start at}` to the end of the URL, and highlight ranges by adding `#L{start}-L{end}`. So, for the `check1arg` function, you can do [https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/17a72a9634734e009094fd8b48e985b8597ced6a/src/main/util.c#L496-L505](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/17a72a9634734e009094fd8b48e985b8597ced6a/src/main/util.c#L496-L505) :-)

Comment: It looks to me that the behaviour of `switch` is pretty in line with the doc. The only thing that might be more clear is that `NULL` is returned (invisibly) if the expression result is not listed in the alternatives (and no default is provided).

Comment: I believe the answer to the question is "it's a design choice". I'm not sure how to explain it, but one explanation  might be that it's easier/cleaner to program an error or warning on top of  the current implementation that to suppress a warning or error on top of the implementation you expected, so the current approach is more flexible.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper You've answered the wrong question. The question is about how I've misunderstood the docs, not why `switch` works as it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already stated in the comments by @MrFlick, the warning is returned when you don't provide alternatives and not if the expression ends up having a value which is different from the alternatives you provided (that looks like your interpretation).

The doc mentions this warning because of the signature of `switch`:

```
> switch
function (EXPR, ...)  .Primitive("switch")
```

You see the `...`; they are optional additional arguments. You usually don't get errors or warnings if you don't provide additional arguments to a function accepting `...`. `switch` is pretty uncharacteristic in this behaviour and that's why the warning is documented.

Another point is that, in your example, you do get an output: it's `NULL`, returned invisibly, which is clearly documented in the "Value" section:

> The value of one of the elements of ‘...’, or ‘NULL’, invisibly
> (whenever no element is selected).
>
> The result has the visibility (see ‘invisible’) of the element
> evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

A call to `switch()` evaluates to `NULL` if none of the arguments get matched to the supplied value. If `EXPR` evaluates to a `character` you can specify a default value by including an unnamed argument. If `EXPR` evaluates to integer, numeric or logical you cannot specify a default for it. You can always use a different conditional operator if this is too limiting.